# Db2: How to insert new and update existing data?

Tags: sql, merge, db2, insert-update

I am using the IBM Db2 database system.  I have a table with 3 columns (1 primary key and others) that I fill after reading from a CSV file. It happens that sometimes I get a repeated data from my file so in this case I need to ignore it.

My problem here is that I can't found the correct Db2 SQL statement that will do Insert Or Update. With my current solution I get an exception in my code:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505,
>   SQLERRMC=1;DB2INST1.TI_APGROUP_0, DRIVER=4.12.55

Is there a simple way to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that does what I want but I don't know if it's the best way or not ! Anyway I post it to help who's facing the same problem but if anyone's have another suggestion it's welcome :

```
MERGE INTO KDDBD01.KDTCTCT AS CT USING (SELECT COUNT(ADR_MAIL_UTIL) FROM KDDBD01.KDTCTCT) ON (CT.ADR_MAIL_UTIL = :contactEmail) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (CT.ADR_MAIL_UTIL) VALUES (:contactEmail)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IMPORT` command in Db2 has a `INSERT_UPDATE` option. You can read here about the [IMPORT command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html).

If your data is already in the database then consider using the [`MERGE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) statement.

Both, in their context, to insert new and update existing data based on some rules.

Comment: I am trying with this query :
`MERGE INTO KDDBD01.KDTCTCT AS CT
 USING (SELECT ADR_MAIL_UTIL FROM KDDBD01.KDTCTCT) AS CT1(ADR_MAIL_UTIL)
 ON (CT.ADR_MAIL_UTIL = CT1.ADR_MAIL_UTIL)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (CT.ADR_MAIL_UTIL) 
 VALUES ('Boite mail generique')`
but I get `Warning:   DB2 SQL Warning: SQLCODE=100, SQLSTATE=02000, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.12.56
SQLState:  02000
ErrorCode: 100`

Comment: That warning  (SQLCODE = 100 ) just means that no rows were found .  It is not an error.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's because `SELECT ADR_MAIL_UTIL FROM KDDBD01.KDTCTCT` doesn't return any row when I execute it for the first time and it's totally logical ! Because in my case I want to insert data only when it's not existant. I am confused I can't find a solution for this query